# Connecting to 4D database using Microstrategy

Tags: microstrategy, 4d-database

Is there a way to connect to a 4D database from Microstrategy?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever find a solution to this?  The problem is all the 4D Devs live on the 4D forums and don't visit SO so much. Having a quick look at a Microstrategy it should be able to connect to 4D as a SQL source-you would need the 4D SQL drivers in your Microstrategy (sorry don't know Microstrategy at all) and the developer of the 4D system will have had to allow an SQL Connection on their system(this is just a setting on the server) In my previous role we used a product called Phocas(similar to Microstrategy) and that was consuming data from 4D and from Sage and others too.. Hope that helps!